# contact form plugin conditional notification emails

Tags: plugin-contactform, plugin-contactformextensions

I would like to be able to use case or if statements to include templates for the notification email, as overridden by the contact form extension plugin. However, no matter what I've tried, the first include is used. (in this case, an order form template, when sometime it should be the job application template or contact template).

example code:

```
% if submission.form == "Bestelformulier" %}
    {% include 'example template 1' %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'example template 2' %}
{% endif %}
```

I have tried using "submission.formName" as well.

The setting to override the notification works fine, using this file, its just what happens in the file doesn't seem to line up and work.
Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Just as an experiment see what {{ submission.form }} outputs in your template to check what it's outputting.

Comment: @user3788089 when {{ submission.form  }} is include, and the form is submitted, the page now redirects to a different form, instead of the thankyou page.... which makes no sense. Further, no template is used for the email, only the from email and from name are included